# Putting suitable constraints on the `Find` family of functions

Tags: fitting

Can any of the `Find` group of functions be used to get a good curve-fit for a range of data, if the value of $f(1)$ is known, and the value of $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}f(n)$ is also known?

*eg*

```
data={{3,0.07639},{4,0.14744},{5,0.20324},{6,0.2458},{7,0.27886},{8,0.30435},{9,0.32526},{10,0.34206},{11,0.3564},{12,0.36824},{13,0.37809},{14,0.38694},{15,0.39419},{16,0.40115},{17,0.40695`},{18,0.41292},{19,0.41743},{20,0.42135},{21,0.42558},{22,0.42932},{23,0.4327}};
```

$f(1)$ & $f(2)$ are undefined, but I know $f(3)=11/144$. I also know $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}f(n)=1/2$.

I tried

```
g[n_] := 1/(n + 1/Log[n])
const = c /. Solve[1/2 - c*g[3] == 11/144, c][[1]];
f[n_] := 1/2 - const*g[n]
```

which gives a fairly good fit for `f[x]`, but was based on guesswork. I was wondering whether any oconstraints could be put on the `Find` (`FindFormula`, etc.) family of inbuilt functions to get a better fit for the above?

Comment: you can work with `LinearModelFit` and `Weights`, assign a large weight to the point that is known to be exact.  Also play with numbers at large `n` to enforce your infinite limit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fix the value at infinity by using [`LinearOffsetFunction`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LinearOffsetFunction.html) and a basis of functions that vanish at infinity.  I'll show an example with a (negative) power function basis `x^-Range[n]`.

What remains is to determine `n` for the best fit.  Here we can see how well a basis can fit the data:

```
1 - Table[LinearModelFit[
    data,
    x^-Range[n], x,
    IncludeConstantBasis -> False,
    LinearOffsetFunction -> (1/2 &)]["AdjustedRSquared"],
  {n, 2, Length@data - 1}
  ]
(*
  {0.000105398, 8.33657*10^-6, 1.35996*10^-6, 7.8618*10^-7, 
   5.26986*10^-7, 4.18325*10^-7, 3.74131*10^-7, 3.63729*10^-7, 
   3.61571*10^-7, 3.95505*10^-7, 4.23729*10^-7, 3.48624*10^-7, 
   3.97022*10^-7, 4.61365*10^-7, 2.04398*10^-6, 
   7.21775*10^-6, 0.00132212, 0.000927684, 0.00819669}
*)
```

There are several with an adjusted R-squared differing from `1` by less than `10^-6`.  The problem as `n` increases is that oscillations will creep in between the data points.  One approach to minimizing the excess oscillation is to minimize the integral of the square of the second derivative.  Below is an objective function we can use to find a good fit with minimal oscillation:

```
obj[n_, acc_] := Module[{lmf},
  lmf = LinearModelFit[
    data,
    x^-Range[n], x,
    IncludeConstantBasis -> False,
    LinearOffsetFunction -> (1/2 &)];
  Sow[lmf, n];
  If[1 - lmf["AdjustedRSquared"] < acc, 
   NIntegrate[lmf''[x]^2, {x, Min@data[[All, 1]], Max@data[[All, 1]]}],
   Infinity]
  ]
```

To find the best fit we apply the `obj` to a suitable range of `n`.  From the table above, we could start at `3` and end at 4 less than the length of the data.

```
n1 = 3; n2 = 4;
bestfit = With[{
   maxmodels = Reap[
     Ordering[Table[obj[n, 1*^-6], {n, n1, Length@data - n2}], 1],
     Range[n1, Length@data - n2]
     ]},
  First@*First@*Extract @@ Reverse@maxmodels]
```

Inspect:

```
bestfit[x]
(*  1/2 + 68.2251/x^5 - 65.5702/x^4 + 24.9918/x^3 - 2.96082/x^2 - 1.47449/x  *)

Plot[bestfit[x], {x, 1, 30},
 Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[Medium], Point@data}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Extrapolation to the left (`x < 3`) seems unreliable, but that shouldn't be surprising with negative powers.

Comment: thanks for the different approach - nice fit for values (+1), will see how compares with larger predicted value (computation may take a while).

Comment: the more data I get, the more it seems likely that the odd exponents have a negative coefficient, and the even ones are positive. However, `x^1` is the odd one out in all of these `best-fit` models - it always has a positive coefficient. Is there any way to *force* MMA to look for a negative coeffineint for *all* odd exponents, and a positive for all even?

Comment: @martin  Probably not with `LinearModelFit`, but constraints can be used with `FindFit`.  I should say I don't understand why you are predisposed to getting alternating signs.  You can remove `1/x` (use the basis `x^-Range[2, n]`), but the fit doesn't look so good...

Comment: tried `expr[datalist_, n_] := Module[{a, b, c},
  a = x[#] & /@ Range@n; b = (1/x^# & /@ Reverse@Range@n); 
  c = FindFit[
       datalist, (1/2 + Total[Times @@ # & /@ Transpose@{a, b}]), a, 
       x][[#, 2]] & /@ Range@n;
  (1/2 + Total[Times @@ # & /@ Transpose@{c, b}])]` eg `expr[data, 5]` - gives similar result. Agreed about poor fit for alternating signs.

Answer (score 1):

```
data = {{3, 11/144}, {4, 0.14744}, {5, 0.20324}, {6, 0.2458}, {7, 
   0.27886}, {8, 0.30435}, {9, 0.32526}, {10, 0.34206}, {11, 
   0.3564}, {12, 0.36824}, {13, 0.37809}, {14, 0.38694}, {15, 
   0.39419}, {16, 0.40115}, {17, 0.40695`}, {18, 0.41292}, {19, 
   0.41743}, {20, 0.42135}, {21, 0.42558}, {22, 0.42932}, {23, 
   0.4327}}; AppendTo[data, {100000, 1/2}];
weights = Join[{100}, ConstantArray[.1, Length@data - 2], {100}]

nlm = NonlinearModelFit[data, a + b/1/(n + 1/Log[n]), {a, b}, n, 
  Weights -> weights]

Show[Plot[nlm[x], {x, 0, 20}], ListPlot[data], Frame -> True]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
nlm[3] - 11/144 // N
(*3.42796*10^-6*)

nlm[1000000000]
(* 0.500041*)
```

Comment: thanks for showing me how to use weights (+1). Essentially I am left with the same formula though (ie `1/2 - const * 1/(n + 1/Log[n])`). I was wondering whether a `Find` function could suggest other forms to me, but keep the known `f[3]` and known limit.

Comment: @martin A good guess needs knowledge about the underlying problem. There are gazillions of functional forms to try. Doing it blindly is possible but somewhat nonsensical

Comment: ok, yes, you are right of course - I was being a bit over hopeful! Thanks for the help with the weights.